# Errors on an alternate index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, routes

I have an index page with lots of detail and want to create a summary index page; but it doesn't display correctly. Some kind of routing/scope problem I suspect.

I created a page called `years/index-summary.html.erb`. The same code that works in the `years/index.html.erb` page results in an error. `years` is a join between `locations` and `people`.

I added `get 'summary' => 'years#index-summary'` to `routes.rb.`

The code that works in `index` but not `index-summary`

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
<tr><td> <%= render 'newcon' %></td></tr>
    <% @years.each do |year| %>
<tr>
       <td class="active"></td>
            <td class="active"> On <%= year.year_date.strftime('%d' ' ' '%b' ' ' '%Y') %>, <strong> <%= year.person.try(:full_name) %> </strong> was a </td>
            <td class="active"> <strong><%= year.title %> </strong> at</td>
            <td class="active"> <strong> <%= year.location.try(:address) %>, <%= year.location.try(:city) %> </strong> which was a </td>
            <td class="active"> <strong> <%= year.resto ? 'restaurant' : '' %> <%= year.resto_name? ? " named \"#{year.resto_name}\". " : '' %> <%= year.resid ? 'Residence' : '' %> </strong> </td>
        <% end %>
</tr>
</table>
```

The error is

```
Project/crores5/app/views/years/index-summary.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #9 [the last line in this code segment]):

<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
<tr><td> <%= render 'newcon' %></td></tr>
    <% @years.each do |year| %>
```

As I said it works fine if I paste the code into index.html.erb and go to `/years'. Running in development mode on a Mac with Puma.

Thank you for any help. A Rails newbie.

https://bitbucket.org/MtnBiker/crores5

Or maybe there is a better way to tackle this need. I used the detailed index page while entering data into the database (via Rails), but for the public the simplified page should be the default and there would be a link to the detailed (index) page which has two other long text fields.

Comment: are you setting the @years variable properly ?, it might be possible you are setting it only in the 'index' action.

Comment: Maybe. But what action do I need to define? In other words, I get that the index page calls the index action in the controller, but no idea what to do in this case. But I'll read Controllers in the guides. Newbie.

Answer (score 0):

@fanta. You got me thinking. I found the action was `index-summary`. I renamed the new file `summary.html.erb` because wanted to avoid confusion with hyphens (method names with hyphens don't work and when I substituted an underscore, it still didn't work, so moved on). Changed the route accordingly, created an action `summary` in the `years` controller and copied from index and all is well. I'm sure there are cleaner ways to do this, but I'm up and running.